# How to extract perticular array value from multidimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How can I get the list of all ids from the array given below,

```
$filteredZips=[{
    "id": 21,
    "distance": "0"
},
{
    "id": 20,
    "distance": "3.9399923305414037"
},
{
    "id": 29,
    "distance": "8.33045537474091"
}]
```

Expected result will be :

```
$id = array('21','20','29');
```

Comment: i must say it's not an array it's a json data can you please share your code without pj that variable

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called array_column that will grab one column in an array.
First the string needs to be converted to array with Json_decode and second parameter to true.

Then array_column returns your expected output.

No looping is needed.

```
$filteredZips='[{
"id": 21,
"distance": "0"},{
"id": 20,
"distance": "3.9399923305414037"},{
"id": 29,
"distance": "8.33045537474091"}]';

$filteredZipsarr = json_decode($filteredZips,true);

$id = array_column($filteredZipsarr, "id");
Var_dump($id);
```

https://3v4l.org/hFOKR

If you don't need the `$filteredZipsarr` you can make it a one liner:

```
$id = array_column(json_decode($filteredZips,true), "id");
```

Comment: thanks @Andreas, but why its returning null and it has a error "array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given"

Comment: @lopamudra In that case you have not used my code. My code says Json_decode($filteredZips, **true**); the true says return as array. If you say parameter 1 is an object you can not have set parameter 2 in jsondecode as true.

Comment: @ Andreas I have done pj to the array variable($filteredZips) not pr on the above,So in that case do you think i should use json_decode?

Comment: @ Andreas Its a json data

Comment: @lopamudra What are you talking about? What is "pj" and "pr"? Yes, it's json data, that is why the code has the line `$filteredZipsarr = json_decode($filteredZips,true);` decode the json data. I don't understand what your problem is. Have you tried the code and nothing but this code? It seems you are changing the code before you use it.

Comment: `$filteredZipsarr = json_decode($filteredZips,true);` this line returning null,may be for some  UTF8 char in php 7

Comment: @lopamudra Filteredzips can't be what you say it is. See here: https://3v4l.org/9U504 Something must be wrong. If Filteredzips is a correct formatted json the code will work, if is's like you wrote here, a syntax error then of course it will not work. You need to show what filteredzips is. Because the way you wrote it in question is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_map` function:

```
$id = array_map(function($value){
   return $value['id'];
}, $filteredZips);
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decode JSON string to access it as Array of Objects :

```
$filteredZips = json_decode($filteredZips);

$results = array();
foreach ($filteredZips as $zip) {
    $results[] = $zip->id;
}

print_r($results);
```

Check here : https://3v4l.org/kfkhV

Comment: Your code does not return an array from the jsonstring. It's an object.

Comment: @Andreas I have updated answer, `json_decode` will return array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_column` after transform your JSON with `json_decode`

```
$ids = array_column(json_decode($filteredZips, true), 'id');

Array
(
    [0] => 21
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 29
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
$answer = [];
foreach($filteredZips as $array){
    if(isset($array['id'])){
         $answer[]=$array['id'];
    }
}
var_dump($answer);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($filteredZips as $zip) {
    $ids[] = $zip["id"];
 }
var_dump($ids);
```

Dont forget to use json_decode function to get a proper php array.