# How to get particular value in this array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How to get particular value in this array in PHP

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

Comment: It is very simple,$arr[0].key1 . Also kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: It is just a 1-minute job. Please go through the documentation first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract perticular array value from multidimentional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442659/how-to-extract-perticular-array-value-from-multidimentional-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to find specific key with value by using `array_search` function

```
$json = '[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo array_search("value2", $array[0]); //key2
echo $array[0]["key2"] //value2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get specific value from the array by using [PHP array_search() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_search.asp). Below is an example code that you need to follow,

Since provided PHP array is in JSON format you first need to decode it as follows,

```
$jsonArray = '[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]';
$array = json_decode($jsonArray, true);
```

So the decoded array will be like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

)
```

And then you can use `array_search()` Function,

```
<?php

$jsonArray = '[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]';
$array = json_decode($jsonArray, true);
echo array_search("value1", $array[0]); // Search an array for the value "value1" and return its key. In this case the key will be "key1"

?>
```

**Note:**
`array_search()` function is the best bet. But you also can use a `for-loop` to iterate all values and check if matches the value that you need. But I recommend using `array_search()` function.

Hope this helps you!